# useEffect setData not setting data despite values being new

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

so this is the piece of code

```
const handleChange = (e, tipo) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);   //0
    console.log(data[tipo]);   //1
    data[tipo] = e.target.value;
    console.log(data[tipo]);    //2
    console.log(data);    //3
    setData(data);
  };
```

Console.log 2 and 3 tell me that that the manipulated data changed, showing me the char that I inserted, but when I do the setData it does not even fire up the useEffect!

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("____________________________________");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("____________________________________");
  }, [data]);
```

It prints it only once while the data is being requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you made chages to data, set data as follow:

If data is an array:

```
setDate([...data]);
```

And this if data is an object:

```
setDate({...data});
```

React will track ref of data not changes you made inside data so if you want your changes to take affect consider pass a new ref to setData().